# Fuzziness across multiple fields -- only use fuzziness on certain fields

Tags: python, elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-plugin

Is there a way to do a `cross_field` search using fuzziness on only certain columns? For example:

```
match against:
- name (fuzziness=1)
- country (fuzziness=0)
```

So the search "John USA" would match, the search "Jon USA" would match, but the search "John AUS"  would not. How would this be done?

Comment: Does no one answer ES questions on StackOverflow? Is it discouraged or something on their forums (I didn't find their forums helpful either).

Comment: Sometimes it takes much longer for people to answer, you need to be patient ;-)

Comment: And as stated in the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#_literal_tie_breaker_literal): `The fuzziness parameter cannot be used with the cross_fields type.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is written in the documentation and Val said in the comment above, "The fuzziness parameter cannot be used with the cross_fields type".

Based on what I have read [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html) and [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#fuzziness). For the problem you have described, I would use the AUTO value for the fuzziness property. As well, I would just go a bit beyond that and specify that the 'name' column should have more relevance than the country one as you are more likely to match a name rather than a country (due to the structure that you presented for your input).

```
{
   "size": 100,
   "query": {
      "multi_match": {
         "query": "John Doe USA",
         "fields": [
            "name^3",
            "country"
         ],
         "fuzziness": "AUTO",
         "max_expansions": 50,
         "prefix_length": 0
      }
   }
}
```

Hope this helps!